# Pywinauto: Arguments in findbestmatch module

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate detecting controls in multiple views in app, but I'm having trouble with providing arguments to `find_best_control_matches()` function. I saw in documentation that it expects *controls* argument, but i have no idea how to get that, well I don't even know what type it should be. I tried to avoid my proiblem with lack of skill by using other, similar functions like `get_control_names()` or `get_non_text_control_name()` but problem is same - can't figure out what arguments should be passed in.

Comment: Hmm... Why do you need such a low level function? What's the exact problem you're trying to solve? Maybe it can be solved on a WindowSpecification level.

Comment: I'm trying to build something like atuomated detector of controls in specific window. There's a lot of similar views (5-10 edits, ~3 comboboxes, sometimes datatimepicker/checkboxes and always listview) and it's really time consuming to write automated scripts to every one of them by hand. If i could get automaticly type and name of all controls in a current window, then i can use it in self-creating assertion tests etc.

Comment: Method `.print_control_identifiers()` prints all possible `best_match` names for every descendant control (could be called for every view). Window specifications can have 3+ levels if any.

Comment: Yeah it kinda helps, but i have no idea how to extract the list with names which this method returns for every control :( The only way i can think of is making `.split()` for every time there is `[]`